# Проблема с кодировкой reverse-строки

Tags: php, кодировка

В общем, как всегда делать нечего и я решил написать маленький скрипт для перекручивания строк в обратном порядке. Все вменяемо работает, но если вдруг ввести русский текст, то он превращается в кракозябры и не декодится из них(дело даже не в charset). Помогите, что не так?
Сам скрипт:

```
<?php
echo '<center><meta charset="utf-8"><hr>';
$sss=str_split($_POST['txt']);
$m=count($sss);
$i=0;
echo 'Regular text: ';
foreach ($sss as $v)
{
$i++;
$word[$i]=$v;
echo $word[$i];
}
echo '<br><br>Reversed text: ';
$i=$m;
do 
{
echo $word[$i];
$i--;
} while ($i>0);
echo '<hr><a href="index.php">Back</a><hr>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что Ваш код оперирует байтами, а строка похоже юникодная, где для киррилицы идет по два байта на символ (а для японских может и по три, и по четыре байта на символ!).
Естественно, если развернуть строку побайтово, то будет плохо.

Для разворачивания подобных строк смотрите примеры по [ссылке](http://kvz.io/blog/2012/10/09/reverse-a-multibyte-string-in-php/). Также читайте о работе с мультибайтовыми строками.

Answer (score 0):

Вставлю-ка я сюда адский костылек для реверса мультибайтовых.

```
function mb_strev ($string, $encoding = null) {
    if ($encoding === null) {
        $encoding = mb_detect_encoding($string);
    }

    $length = mb_strlen($string, $encoding);
    $reversed = '';
    while($length-- > 0) {
        $reversed .= mb_substring($string, $length, 1, $encoding);
    }
    return $reversed;
}
```